# mount server folder C code

Tags: c, linux, mount

Hi I am trying to write C program that mounts server folder. I tried the following code but it didn't work( print message error 1 Operation not permitted, once I run it with sudo I got error 22 ivalid argument). This look very weird for me.  Any ideas / suggestions ?

```
#include <sys/mount.h>
int main(){ 
const char* server_src_path="ip_address:/myfolder";
const char* local_path="/myLocalFolder";
const char* filesystem="nfs";
mount(server_src_path, local_path,filesystem, MS_MGC_VAL | MS_RDONLY | MS_NOSUID, ""); 
printf("error message %d %s\n",errno, strerror(errno));
return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Here on Stack Overflow, You'll find that questions like yours will not get you an answer and generally discouraged.

Comment: Probably server_src_path or local path is wrong. Or you're not running with the required capabilities. Either way it'll be returning an error code to help, but as it stands the question is unanswerably under specified.

Comment: "didn't work" is very very vague.  Please be more specific.  For this, check at least the return code and shar with us about the error code in errno.  ...maybe errno will even help you to solve our issue on your own ?

Comment: Sorry I edited my post. Should be more clear now. Thanks!

Comment: That's a log better.  Did you read the section in the manual page discussing what causes `mount` to return `EINVAL`

Comment: Well I looked it up but I didn't get the meaning of the error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring briefly to the `mount` manpage (in 2, the section for syscall APIs), which you can read with `man 2 mount`

1. You are missing the third argument, *filesystemtype*, which should be a compile-error unless your prototypes are badly broken.
2. Your `server_src_path` and `local_path` are undeclared identifiers, which is a compile-error.
3. You aren't checking the return value or `errno`.  Usually `perror` is helpful for getting a readable description of the error.

When you do determine what error you're getting, that same manpage will tell you under what conditions this function generates that error.